# Global distribution fitting sharing some parameters without any specification of the bin size in python

Tags: python, global, distribution, data-fitting, symfit

I have several data sets that fit separately very well to a vonMises distribution. I am looking for a way of fitting all of them sharing `mu` but with different `kappas` without to care about the election of the bins.

When one wants to fit with only one model it is quite trivial: `scipy` [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html) does the fit with the raw data. But I have been looking for global fitting using [`symfit`](https://symfit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fitting_types.html#fitting-multiple-datasets) or [`lmfit`](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/faq.html#how-can-i-fit-multiple-data-sets), or in some posts ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40958688/global-fitting-example-with-symfit) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339234/python-and-lmfit-how-to-fit-multiple-datasets-with-shared-parameters)), and in all cases we have to specify x-coordinates and y-coordinates, which means with have previously to choose some bin size for the distribution.

This is some artificial data for only two data sets that could be useful as a example of what I need, though fitting each individually, using `scipy`. (Note that I don't need to care about the election of the bins).

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# creating the data
mu1, mu2 = .05, -.05
sigma1, sigma2 = 3.1, 2.9
n1, n2 = 8000, 9000
y1 = np.random.vonmises(mu1, sigma1, n1)
y2 = np.random.vonmises(mu2, sigma2, n2)

# fitting
dist = st.vonmises
*args1, loc1, scale1 = dist.fit(y1, fscale=1)
*args2, loc2, scale2 = dist.fit(y2, fscale=1)

x1 = np.linspace(np.min(y1), np.max(y1), 200)
x2 = np.linspace(np.min(y2), np.max(y2), 200)

pdf_fitted1 = dist.pdf(x1, *args1, loc=loc1, scale=scale1)
pdf_fitted2 = dist.pdf(x2, *args2, loc=loc2, scale=scale2)

# plotting
plt.hist(y1, bins=40, density=True, histtype='step', color='#1f77b4')
plt.hist(y2, bins=40, density=True, histtype='step', color='#ff7f0e')
plt.plot(x1, pdf_fitted1, color='#1f77b4')
plt.plot(x2, pdf_fitted2, color='#ff7f0e')
plt.show()
```

I'd be glad if someone could help with that, thanks in advance. Any answer or comment would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for this excellent question. In principle you should be able to solve this using `symfit` out of the box, but your question brought to light some minor issues. `symfit` is very much a project in flux, so unfortunately this will happen from time to time. But I created a workaround that should work on the current master branch, and I hope to release a new version soon which will address these issues.

In principle this is a combination of the global fitting examples you already found with the [LikeLihood](https://symfit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fitting_types.html#likelihood) objective function. With LogLikelihood, you don't need to bin but instead use the measurements directly. However, LikeLihood does not seem to handle multi component models properly yet so I included a fixed version of LogLikelihood.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from symfit import (
    Fit, parameters, variables, exp, cos, CallableModel, pi, besseli
)
from symfit.core.objectives import LogLikelihood
from symfit.core.minimizers import *
from symfit.core.printing import SymfitNumPyPrinter

# symbolic bessel is not converted into numerical yet, this monkey-patches it.
def _print_besseli(self, expr):
    return 'scipy.special.iv({}, {})'.format(*expr.args)

SymfitNumPyPrinter._print_besseli = _print_besseli

# creating the data
mu1, mu2 = .05, -.05  # Are these supposed to be opposite sign?
sigma1, sigma2 = 3.5, 2.5
n1, n2 = 8000, 9000
np.random.seed(42)
x1 = np.random.vonmises(mu1, sigma1, n1)
x2 = np.random.vonmises(mu2, sigma2, n2)

# Create a model for `n` different datasets.
n = 2
x, *xs = variables('x,' + ','.join('x_{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, n + 1)))
ys = variables(','.join('y_{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, n + 1)))
mu, kappa = parameters('mu, kappa')
kappas = parameters(','.join('k_{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, n + 1)),
                    min=0, max=10)
mu.min, mu.max = - np.pi, np.pi  # Bound to 2 pi

# Create a model template, who's symbols we will replace for each component.
template = exp(kappa * cos(x - mu)) / (2 * pi * besseli(0, kappa))
model = CallableModel(
    {y_i: template.subs({kappa: k_i, x: x_i}) for y_i, x_i, k_i in zip(ys, xs, kappas)}
)
print(model)

class AlfredosLogLikelihood(LogLikelihood):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        evaluated_func = super(LogLikelihood, self).__call__(
            *args, **kwargs
        )

        ans = - sum([np.nansum(np.log(component))
                     for component in evaluated_func])
        return ans

fit = Fit(model, x_1=x1, x_2=x2, objective=AlfredosLogLikelihood)

x_axis = np.linspace(- np.pi, np.pi, 101)
fit_result = fit.execute()
print(fit_result)
x1_result, x2_result = model(x_1=x_axis, x_2=x_axis, **fit_result.params)

# plotting
plt.hist(x1, bins=40, density=True, histtype='step', color='#1f77b4')
plt.hist(x2, bins=40, density=True, histtype='step', color='#ff7f0e')
plt.plot(x_axis, x1_result, color='#1f77b4')
plt.plot(x_axis, x2_result, color='#ff7f0e')
plt.show()
```

This outputs the following:

```
[y_1(x_1; k_1, mu) = exp(k_1*cos(mu - x_1))/(2*pi*besseli(0, k_1)),
 y_2(x_2; k_2, mu) = exp(k_2*cos(mu - x_2))/(2*pi*besseli(0, k_2))]

Parameter Value        Standard Deviation
k_1       3.431673e+00 None
k_2       2.475649e+00 None
mu        1.030791e-02 None
Status message         b'CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH'
Number of iterations   13
```

[image]

I hope this get's you in the right direction, and thank you for bringing this bug to light ;).

Comment: Great answer @tBuLi, thanks. Although I am having this error: No module named 'symfit.core.printing'. I am using `symfit` version 0.4.6

Comment: Yeah I'm afraid you will have to use the current master branch for this to work, I don't think I can find a solution in 0.4.6.

Comment: Can you please tell me where can find it? In [pypi](https://pypi.org/search/?q=symfit) I just found the version 0.4.6.

Comment: Oh, yes @tBuLi, the `mu`'s are supposed to be opposite sign, but just in order to test that the algorithm was fitting well (as in this case, where `mu` is almost zero).

Comment: You can find it on github: https://github.com/tBuLi/symfit. You'll need to clone the master branch and then install that in pip

Comment: Glad to hear it worked @Alfredo :). As for the regression coefficient, it does not exist for likelihood fitting, hence the `nan` and the warning. In Pull Request (PR) 221 this is fixed, which will be merged soon to create symfit 0.5.0. The same goes for the standard deviations:  the solution I gave you above does not implement the derivatives of the loglikelihood function so no standard deviation can be calculated. However, by now I fully fixed your issue in this [PR237](https://github.com/tBuLi/symfit/pull/237), so if you run that instead you should get them :).

Comment: Oh of course, of course (I don't know what I was thinking about). Thank you very much for these last suggestions and also for your time :) (`symfit` is great btw)